# How to create a url for notification in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i want to send an email to user after he sign-up with code.for ex

http://192.168.1.51:3000/logins/activate/435546dgfd757676657 #link contains in an email

how can i create the above URL in my notifier model.
i know following way

```
url_for :controller=>'logins', :action=>'activate', :id=>'435546dgfd757676657' , :host=>'http://192.168.1.54:3000'
```

Which is working properly.
what i want that  host should not be hard coded. How can i get host with port in a model.

In controller i can find it using follwing ways

```
request.host_with_port
```

Please provide me correct ruby way for doing same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the host in your environment.rb file.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

As your host probably changes depending of your environment (development, test, production), it's better to put that config line inside the environment file.

After that, every link in emails will be made with that host. You don't have to provide it in the view anymore.